# Limitation of SQL Server recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data structure

[image]

PresentationSession: 1 day has 2 sessions: morning=1, afternoon=2. Some presentation is the whole day presentation, some only has morning or afternoon.

dayofweek column represents the day of the week for the presentation-eg Monday=2, Tues=3...

Maximum session is the maximum of consecutive sessions a presentation last. Presentation has to be confined within a multiple of a week. For example, if the presentation take place in Wed, Th, Fr and the max Session is 12 then the presentation last 2 weeks. (1 day has 2 sessions). However, if there is a holiday in says Thu, then it is still 2 weeks but 10 sessions, hence the MaxSession is still 12. On the other side of the spectrum, if the MaxSession is only 2, then there will be 3 different presentation on that week.

Newblock marks the start of the week, 0= new start of the week.

rn is the sequential number of the day

My goal is to aggregate the records and consolidate the information to a more human readable format with fromDate, endDate, presentationId, Name (see illustration)

[image]

The following recursive cte script does the job just fine but it only works with a data set of 50 records. It will error out with a data set of 2000+ records.

The error is:

```
Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 110
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.
```

At first, I thought Oracle had the same issue but further checking shows that the recursion limitation is isolated to SQL Server only!! The exact same data set works in Oracle like a charm.

Below is the "working" cte statement in SQL Server (up to 50 records)

```
with r (PresentationDate, Presentationid,Name,MaxSession,PresentationDay,rn,blocknum,pos,lastmaxrow) AS
(
  select PresentationDate, Presentationid, Name, MaxSession, PresentationDay, rn,1,1,MaxSession
  from presentation 
  where rn=1
  union all
  select u.PresentationDate, u.Presentationid,  u.Name, u.MaxSession, u.PresentationDay, u.rn,
  case 
    when r.pos=r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then
         r.blocknum+1
         else r.blocknum
  end,
  case 
    when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then 1
    else r.pos+1
  end,
  case
    when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then r.lastmaxrow
    else r.MaxSession
  end
  from presentation u
  join r
  on u.Presentationid=r.Presentationid and u.rn=r.rn+1
  )
  select min(r.PresentationDate) as fromDate, max(r.PresentationDate) as todate, 
          r.Presentationid, r.Name
  from r
  group by r.Presentationid, r.Name, r.blocknum
  order by r.Name, r.blocknum
```

So my questions are:

1) Is there something in my "working" code that could be improved to bypass the recursive limitation in SQL Server?

2) Is there a config switch in SQL Server that I can flip to allow recursive more than 100 times?

3) If the answer for the 2 above questions is no, is it possible to convert the recursive statement to non recursive statement without using cursor? I understand I may need multiple statements with other temporary table, but if the use of cursor is not necessary, I prefer not using it.

I have a full test sample in excel if needed. Since I do not know if I can upload it here, I attached an extract of my sample hopefully it is large enough to illustrate my point.

```
PresentationDate,PresentationDay,PresentationSession,PresentationID,Name,DayOfWeek,MaxSession,rn,newblock
2016-05-24 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,1,0
2016-05-24 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,2,1
2016-05-25 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,3,1
2016-05-25 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,4,1
2016-05-26 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,5,1
2016-05-26 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,6,1
2016-05-27 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,7,1
2016-05-27 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,8,1
2016-05-31 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,9,0
2016-05-31 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,10,1
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,11,1
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,12,1
2016-06-02 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,13,1
2016-06-02 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,14,1
2016-06-03 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,15,1
2016-06-03 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,16,1
2016-06-07 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,17,0
2016-06-07 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,18,1
2016-06-08 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,19,1
2016-06-08 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,20,1
2016-06-09 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,21,1
2016-06-09 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,22,1
2016-06-10 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,23,1
2016-06-10 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,24,1
2016-06-14 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,25,0
2016-06-14 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,26,1
2016-06-15 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,27,1
2016-06-15 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,28,1
2016-06-16 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,29,1
2016-06-16 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,30,1
2016-06-17 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,31,1
2016-06-17 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,32,1
2016-06-21 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,33,0
2016-06-21 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,34,1
2016-06-22 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,35,1
2016-06-22 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,36,1
2016-06-23 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,37,1
2016-06-23 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,38,1
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,39,1
2016-06-24 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,40,1
2016-06-28 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,41,0
2016-06-28 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,42,1
2016-06-29 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,43,1
2016-06-29 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,44,1
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,45,1
2016-06-30 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,46,1
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,47,1
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,48,1
2016-07-05 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,49,0
2016-07-05 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,50,1
2016-07-06 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,51,1
2016-07-06 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,52,1
2016-07-07 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,53,1
2016-07-07 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,54,1
2016-07-08 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,55,1
2016-07-08 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,56,1
2016-07-12 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,57,0
2016-07-12 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,58,1
2016-07-13 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,59,1
2016-07-13 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,60,1
2016-07-14 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,61,1
2016-07-14 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,62,1
2016-07-15 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,63,1
2016-07-15 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,64,1
2016-07-19 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,65,0
2016-07-19 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,66,1
2016-07-20 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,67,1
2016-07-20 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,68,1
2016-07-21 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,69,1
2016-07-21 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,70,1
2016-07-22 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,71,1
2016-07-22 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,72,1
2016-07-26 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,73,0
2016-07-26 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,74,1
2016-07-27 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,75,1
2016-07-27 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,76,1
2016-07-28 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,77,1
2016-07-28 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,78,1
2016-07-29 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,79,1
2016-07-29 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,80,1
2016-08-02 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,81,0
2016-08-02 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,82,1
2016-08-03 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,83,1
2016-08-03 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,84,1
2016-08-04 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,85,1
2016-08-04 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,86,1
2016-08-05 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,87,1
2016-08-05 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,88,1
2016-08-09 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,89,0
2016-08-09 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,90,1
2016-08-10 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,91,1
2016-08-10 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,92,1
2016-08-11 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,93,1
2016-08-11 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,94,1
2016-08-12 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,95,1
2016-08-12 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,96,1
2016-08-16 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,97,0
2016-08-16 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,98,1
2016-08-17 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,99,1
2016-08-17 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,100,1
2016-08-18 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,101,1
2016-08-18 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,102,1
2016-08-19 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,103,1
2016-08-19 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,104,1
2016-08-23 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,105,0
2016-08-23 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,106,1
2016-08-24 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,107,1
2016-08-24 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,108,1
2016-08-25 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,109,1
2016-08-25 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,110,1
2016-08-26 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,111,1
2016-08-26 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,112,1
2016-08-30 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,113,0
2016-08-30 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,114,1
2016-08-31 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,115,1
2016-08-31 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,116,1
2016-09-01 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,117,1
2016-09-01 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,118,1
2016-09-02 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,119,1
2016-09-02 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,120,1
2016-09-06 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,121,0
2016-09-06 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,122,1
2016-09-07 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,123,1
2016-09-07 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,124,1
2016-09-08 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,125,1
2016-09-08 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,126,1
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,127,1
2016-09-09 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,128,1
2016-09-13 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,129,0
2016-09-13 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,130,1
2016-09-14 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,131,1
2016-09-14 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,132,1
2016-09-15 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,133,1
2016-09-15 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,134,1
2016-09-16 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,135,1
2016-09-16 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,136,1
2016-09-20 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,137,0
2016-09-20 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,138,1
2016-09-21 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,139,1
2016-09-21 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,140,1
2016-09-22 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,141,1
2016-09-22 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,142,1
2016-09-23 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,143,1
2016-09-23 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,144,1
2016-09-27 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,145,0
2016-09-27 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,146,1
2016-09-28 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,147,1
2016-09-28 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,148,1
2016-09-29 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,149,1
2016-09-29 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,150,1
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,151,1
2016-09-30 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,152,1
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,153,0
2016-10-04 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,154,1
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,155,1
2016-10-05 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,156,1
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,157,1
2016-10-06 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,158,1
2016-10-07 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,159,1
2016-10-07 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,160,1
2016-10-11 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,161,0
2016-10-11 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,162,1
2016-10-12 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,163,1
2016-10-12 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,164,1
2016-10-13 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,165,1
2016-10-13 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,166,1
2016-10-14 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,167,1
2016-10-14 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,168,1
2016-10-18 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,169,0
2016-10-18 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,170,1
2016-10-19 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,171,1
2016-10-19 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,172,1
2016-10-20 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,173,1
2016-10-20 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,174,1
2016-10-21 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,175,1
2016-10-21 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,176,1
2016-10-25 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,177,0
2016-10-25 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,178,1
2016-10-26 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,179,1
2016-10-26 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,180,1
2016-10-27 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,181,1
2016-10-27 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,182,1
2016-10-28 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,183,1
2016-10-28 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,184,1
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,185,0
2016-11-01 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,186,1
2016-11-02 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,187,1
2016-11-02 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,188,1
2016-11-03 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,189,1
2016-11-03 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,190,1
2016-11-04 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,191,1
2016-11-04 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,192,1
2016-11-08 00:00:00.000,3,1,ID1,ABC,3,8,193,0
2016-11-08 00:00:00.000,3,2,ID1,ABC,3,8,194,1
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000,4,1,ID1,ABC,4,8,195,1
2016-11-09 00:00:00.000,4,2,ID1,ABC,4,8,196,1
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000,5,1,ID1,ABC,5,8,197,1
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000,5,2,ID1,ABC,5,8,198,1
2016-11-11 00:00:00.000,6,1,ID1,ABC,6,8,199,1
2016-11-11 00:00:00.000,6,2,ID1,ABC,6,8,200,1
```

Comment: When you say sql, do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server

Comment: **(1)** Don't use images. There are not searchable and their content can be copied. Please replace them with text.  **(2)** You gave way too much information, both columns and explanations, that are not relevant to your question **(3)** Your data sample is problematic. Too big and does not represent a real scenario where there is more than 1 PresentationID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you can bypass 100 iterations default limitation by specifying `OPTION (MAXRECURSION X)` with your query. Where X is maximum number of iterations, and it can have values from 0 (no limitation) up to 32767 (maximum defined limitation).

If you are uncertain how many iterations you might expect or amount of expected iterations exceeds 32767 then you might consider using `MAXRECURSION 0` option.

```
with r (PresentationDate, Presentationid,Name,MaxSession,PresentationDay,rn,blocknum,pos,lastmaxrow) AS
(
  select PresentationDate, Presentationid, Name, MaxSession, PresentationDay, rn,1,1,MaxSession
  from presentation 
  where rn=1
  union all
  select u.PresentationDate, u.Presentationid,  u.Name, u.MaxSession, u.PresentationDay, u.rn,
  case 
    when r.pos=r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then
         r.blocknum+1
         else r.blocknum
  end,
  case 
    when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then 1
    else r.pos+1
  end,
  case
    when r.pos = r.lastmaxrow or u.newblock=0 then r.lastmaxrow
    else r.MaxSession
  end
  from presentation u
  join r
  on u.Presentationid=r.Presentationid and u.rn=r.rn+1
  )
  select min(r.PresentationDate) as fromDate, max(r.PresentationDate) as todate, 
          r.Presentationid, r.Name
  from r
  group by r.Presentationid, r.Name, r.blocknum
  order by r.Name, r.blocknum
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

You can read about MAXRECURSION in context of CTE [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rafal. I think adding the maxrecursion 0 as you suggested works. I am not sure who is the coward that downvoted you without further explanation. Without other people chiming in, I think your solution IS the answer..

Comment: I am happy it worked for you @user1205746. It doesn't really matter who down voted as I was more curious why? We all make mistakes once in a while and I would be happy to correct answer if there was one.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I really appreciate your assistance. It DOES really helped. I have been hitting my head against the wall the whole day yesterday before putting it out and I got answer just like that!! Again very much appreciated!

Comment: There is always an option the coward just had to get down from the train. **(1)** You didn't mention that MAXRECURSION can be changed not just to 0 but also to any value between 1 and 32,767 and by that avoid endless loop. **(2)** You didn't mention that the default value on MAXRECURSION is 100 and this why the query worked on 50 records but not on 2000 **(3)** You didn't supply a link, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx **(4)** **you failed to see that this a GAPS AND ISLANDS issue** http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions

Comment: Yeah, I guess I extend my answer when I get from my train.

Comment: .. and there is nothing recursive about "recursive" queries

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz There is nothing wrong in writing your own answer you know. Doesn't hurt - it even helps other people sometimes.

Comment: You are invited to check my user and take a look at my answers. Sorry, have to drive now.

Comment: This is the answer that works for me until a better answer is found. I guess when you are thirsty, even a drop of water will be appreciated than no water.

Answer (score 0):

**Gaps and Islands**

Here is the minimum query that demonstrate the concept.
There are plenty of tutorials that explain this type of problem in detail.

```
select      PresentationID
           ,min(PresentationDate)   as from_date
           ,max(PresentationDate)   as to_date

from       (select      PresentationID
                       ,PresentationDate

                       ,dense_rank () over
                        (
                            partition by    PresentationID
                            order by        PresentationDate    
                        )   as dr          

            from        presentation
            ) p

group by    PresentationID
           ,dateadd(day,-dr,PresentationDate)

order by    PresentationID  
           ,to_date
```

---

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
| PresentationID | from_date  |  to_date   |
+----------------+------------+------------+
| ID1            | 2016-05-24 | 2016-05-27 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-31 | 2016-06-03 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-07 | 2016-06-10 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-14 | 2016-06-17 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-21 | 2016-06-24 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-28 | 2016-07-01 |
| ID1            | 2016-07-05 | 2016-07-08 |
| ID1            | 2016-07-12 | 2016-07-15 |
| ID1            | 2016-07-19 | 2016-07-22 |
| ID1            | 2016-07-26 | 2016-07-29 |
| ID1            | 2016-08-02 | 2016-08-05 |
| ID1            | 2016-08-09 | 2016-08-12 |
| ID1            | 2016-08-16 | 2016-08-19 |
| ID1            | 2016-08-23 | 2016-08-26 |

...
```

**Here are some data That will help you to understand what's going on here.**

```
+----------------+------------------+----+------------+
| PresentationID | PresentationDate | dr |  dateadd   |
+----------------+------------------+----+------------+
| ID1            | 2016-05-24       |  1 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-24       |  1 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-25       |  2 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-25       |  2 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-26       |  3 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-26       |  3 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-27       |  4 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-27       |  4 | 2016-05-23 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-31       |  5 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-05-31       |  5 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-01       |  6 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-01       |  6 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-02       |  7 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-02       |  7 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-03       |  8 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-03       |  8 | 2016-05-26 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-07       |  9 | 2016-05-29 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-07       |  9 | 2016-05-29 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-08       | 10 | 2016-05-29 |
| ID1            | 2016-06-08       | 10 | 2016-05-29 |
...
```